# use 'X-Forwarded-For' instead of '$remote_ip' in pluggin 'rate-limiting'

Tags: nginx, lua, architecture, api-gateway, kong

We have many layers before `Kong` server.

How can we use the plugin `rate-limiting` to limit requests by every enduser's client IP?

I want the plugin `rate-limiting` to read the header `X-Forwarded-For` to get the users real IP. But I think it is using `$remote_ip` by `rate-limiting`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like we are in the same race, we are also trying to implement the same but so far no luck. Did you get any clue so far? I am planning to use set_real_ip_from , and real_ip_header.

Comment: yes, pass real $remote_ip to Kong, if you can set the intermediate proxy

Comment: Enabling "proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For  remote_addr" and "real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;" worked, however, I could not find any way around this.

Comment: are you setting this in Kong or somewhere else? I'm trying to use the real IP from X-Forwarded-For, since the call was forwarded to Kong. Using it for the IP Restriction plugin.